# Dmg to Iso on Win 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, iso-image, dmg-image

I was unable to run in cmd dmg2iso.

It throws error that it can run only on 32-bit system and not 64-bit.

Is there some free program that can do that on win 7 64-bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it seems to be a 16-bit EXE dating back to April 2005. As mentioned on its site:

> **DMG2ISO**
>
> Converts compressed (z-lib) dmg images to iso images.
>
> **Provided for historical reasons. You should use DMG2IMG above.**

So the solution is to simply use [DMG2IMG](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/) instead which is still being updated.